# add value to first list (of lists) matching predicate

Tags: loops, clojure, immutability

I have a list of lists and a value. My goal is a new list of lists, where the value is conjed (new first item) to the first list matching a predicate (eg > to the first item of the list). If no list matches the predicate, I want my value to "begin" a new list at the end of lists.

```
if my list is: ['(2 3 4) '(4 5 6 7) '(5 6 7)]
and my value: 3
and my predicate: (comp (partial < my-value) first)
then my result should be: ['(2 3 4) '(3 4 5 6 7) '(5 6 7)]

if my value was: 10
my result should be: ['(2 3 4) '(4 5 6 7) '(5 6 7) '(10)]
```

This problem confuses me, because my imperative mind keeps telling me how easy it should be, but I cannot find an easy (ok, be honest: any) solution. this is my attempt so far:

```
(defn add-to-first-list-that-matches [func value]
  (loop [result []
         remaining-lists list-of-lists
         value-to-add value]
    (if (empty? remaining-lists)
      result
      (let [current-list (first remaining-lists)
            value-matches? (func value-to-add current-list)
            new-list (if value-matches? (conj value-to-add current-list) current-list)]
        (recur (conj new-list result)
               (rest remaining-lists)
               (if-not value-matches? value-to-add nil))))))
```

(it crashes)
please enlighten me with some clojure expression magic :)

btw. I want to solve this as part of the longest-increasing-subsequence problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ye olde lazy-seq:

```
(defn add-to-first-match
  [pred x coll]
  (lazy-seq
    (if-let [s (seq coll)]
      (let [fst (first s)]
        (if (pred fst)
          (cons (conj fst x) (rest s))
          (cons fst (add-to-first-match pred x (rest s)))))
      (cons (list x) nil))))
```

Note: one could further extract `list` into an argument and allow for example also `vector` as element constructor.

Comment: This performs better than my loop-recur. Nice one.

Comment: What is the benefit in this example of using a lazy-seq (instead of just starting with the if expression, which also works)? Is it only for performance?

Comment: Yes, if you take only one element or two of the resulting sequence, the body is not invoked for the other elements. The result is sort of memoized, so if you take the same elements again, the body will also not be invoked again.

Comment: So performance is the same, when I want the whole list anyway, but it's a good thing to do to any function returning a list, because you never know how much of the list is really needed?

Answer (score 4):

This uses loop-recur.

```
(defn add-to-ll
  [ll pred value]
  (loop [[current & unprocessed] ll
         processed []]
    (cond
     (pred current) (concat processed
                            [(cons value current)]
                            unprocessed)
     (empty? unprocessed) (concat processed
                                  [current]
                                  [[value]])
     :else (recur unprocessed
                  (conj processed current)))))


 (def l-l1 [[2 3 4] [4 5 6 7] [5 6 7]])
 (add-to-ll l-l1 (comp (partial < 10) first) 10)
 => ([2 3 4] [4 5 6 7] [5 6 7] [10])

 (add-to-ll l-l1 (comp (partial < 3) first) 3)
 => ([2 3 4] (3 4 5 6 7) [5 6 7])
```

You could also use split-with

```
(defn add-to-ll
  [ll pred value]
  (let [[first-lists [to-change & rest-lists]] (split-with (complement pred) ll)]
    (if to-change
      (concat first-lists [(cons value to-change)] rest-lists)
      (concat ll [[value]]))))
```

Performance wise the first solution should run a bit faster.

Comment: The split-with answer is real neat. I didn't know about split-with

Comment: Thanks, but remember that it requires two lazy traversals of ll because it's equal to [(take-while pred ll) (drop-while pred ll)] (<- this is the exact source code of split-with.). So a loop recur usually runs faster.

Comment: Would you consider the performance impacts a reason not to use your split-with approach? To me it seems like the most elegant solution since there is not much "list-processing" code (like looping or reducing) involved.

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. If you are working on a larger sequence, traversing it twice using split-with costs what RH calls "per-step allocation overhead". When I am trying to max performance, I never use split-with.

Comment: Thanks. Also, I find it funny you refer to him as RH :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn find-index
  "find index of the first item in s matching predicate `pred`"
  [pred s]
  (first (keep-indexed (fn [index item]
                         (if (pred item)
                           index
                           nil))
                       s)))

(defn update-first-match
  "update first item in s that matches `pred` using (f item args*)"
  [s pred f & args]
  (apply update-in s [(or (find-index pred s)
                          (count s))]
         f args))


(def my-lists
  ['(2 3 4) '(4 5 6 7) '(5 6 7)])

(defn add-to-first-list-less-than
  [l n]
  (update-first-match l #(< n (first %)) conj n))

;; usage:

(update-first-match my-lists #(< 5 (first %)) conj 5)

;; or
(add-to-first-list-less-than my-lists 5)
```

Comment: You could also write (when (pred item) index) in line 5.

Comment: @user1944838 I don't really like using (when ...) for pure expressions; I prefer to only use (when ..) for side-effects

Comment: Interesting. I have never heard of this idiom. Could you elaborate more? However, you could still let go of the nil.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt to answer more succinctly using reduce:

```
(defn add-to-first-list-that-matches
  [value lists]
  (let [pred (comp (partial < value) first)
        [found result] (reduce (fn [[found result] el]
                                 (if (and (not found) (pred el))
                                   [true (conj result (cons value el))]
                                   [found (conj result el)]))
                               [false []]
                               lists)]
    (if found
      result
      (conj result (list value)))))
```

I am using the idiom of a vector in reduce to carry multiple values (a boolean to indicate whether a match has been found, plus the modified data structure we are building up). I was also able to combine the various conditions into a single if per element, plus a final post-condition rather than nested conditions or a multi branch cond.

Here is how it works with your examples:

```
user> (add-to-first-list-that-matches 3 ['(2 3 4) '(4 5 6 7) '(5 6 7)])
[(2 3 4) (3 4 5 6 7) (5 6 7)]
user> (add-to-first-list-that-matches 10 ['(2 3 4) '(4 5 6 7) '(5 6 7)])
[(2 3 4) (4 5 6 7) (5 6 7) (10)]
```

Comment: This is exactly the way I wanted to solve it at first. I just couldn't figure out, how reduce should know, whether we already have added the value or not. I'm new to clojure, so I enjoy seeing many different approaches and one thing I learned so far (in this thread) is, that destructing is really a nice thing to use often. Thanks :)